# response()->json() in Laravel re-sorts array by key

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say you have following data:

```
$array = ['23' => 'item', '32' => 'another item', '1' => 'More items'];
```

Using

```
return response()->json($array);
```

Will decode data element following:

```
{
    1  : 'More Items'
    23 : 'Item'
    32 : 'Another Item'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent array resorting put it into object's variable as such:

```
$array = ['23' => 'item', '32' => 'another item', '1' => 'More items'];    
$returnData = ['unsorted' => $array];
return response()->json($returnData);
```

This becomes a problem for `orderBy()` queries. You can alternatively, add `orderBy()->values();`